# texture expends after beveling the corners

Tags: texturing, uv, bevel

[image]

texture expends after beveling the corners, does someone knows how to fix it? thanks a lot

Comment: Hello, Meiying Lu,  you'll have to give us a bit more information. Is this a UV-mapped texture? Is the Bevel a modifier?  Perhaps share your file on blend-exchange.com, so folks can have a look at your particular case.

Comment: ok thanks, i will upload the file if it still not works.

Answer (score 0):

As bevelling adds faces by extending your mesh from the edges, the UV map is distorted by trying to map a texture where there was nothing before.

You'll have to marks your seams again, on the middle edges of your bevel, then unwrap.

Comment: thanks! i realized that if i import the meterial direct from bridge or from blenderkit, the texture are more correct, if i use control+shift+t to import the textures, there will be sometimes not correct with the texture